# How can I use both OR and .find() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my code:

```
$('.mycls1 table tr td, .mycls2 table tr td').css('opacity', '.2');
```

---

Now I want to use two variables instead of `.mycls1` and `.mycls2`, Like this:

```
var mycls1 = $(`.mycls1`),
    mycls2 = $(`.mycls2`);
```

So I have to use `.find()` to select that, like this:

```
mycls1.find('table tr td').css('opacity', '.2');
mycls2.find('table tr td').css('opacity', '.2');
```

See? In this case *(using `.find()`)* forces me to use to two separate lines of code for selecting those two elements.

Anyway, I want to know is it possible to use both `.find()` and OR (`,`) in the same line?

---

Noted that in my example, declaring two variables and initializing those two elements in them is not effective, but in reality it is. So I just need to learn the concept of how can I do that.

Comment: Why aren't you using the "or" selector in the variable declaration?

Comment: @DenisTsoi Because sometimes I need to use one of those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to add elements to collection.

```
mycls1.add(mycls2)....
```

This will add the elements from `mycls2`.

```js
var mycls1 = $(`.mycls1`),
    mycls2 = $(`.mycls2`);

mycls1.add(mycls2).css('opacity', '.2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mycls1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="mycls2">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Also can you please tell me how can I write [these](https://jsfiddle.net/voqnu21d/) two lines in one line?

Comment: I think you didn't pay attention to the fiddle I gave carefully. Both lines refer to the same table and the different between them is `td` and `th`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try below code

```
var mycls = $(`.mycls1, .mycls2`);
mycls.find('table tr td').css('opacity', '.2');
```

Comment: Sometimes I need to use one of those variables.